# How do I download offline javadocs in Android Studio that are accessible using mouse over and ctrl + q?

Tags: android-studio

I do not have an option for "Documentation for SDK". There are other "similar" questions with outdated images and suggestions. I was able to partially get this working by using:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

but this only handles part of the javadocs, not the one provided by the API 29 SDK.

My javadoc window also does not need to be resized because it's too small.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open **SDKManager** and click **SDK Platforms** and make sure to click on the *Checkbox:* **Show Package Details** located at the bottom right corner of the window and download the **Sources file** for your **targetSdk**.